# How to troubleshoot BIRT and JDO classloading issue?

Tags: osgi, jdo, birt, datanucleus, equinox

I am trying to instantiate a JDO-annotated and Datanucleus-enhanced class within a data access method that is getting invoked from a BIRT report via a custom ODA Driver.

BIRT Engine -> ODA Driver -> Data Access Class -> new JDOAnnotatedClass()

But following ClassCastException is being thrown by DataNucleus annotation reader when the constructor of JDO annotated class is invoked.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType cannot be cast to javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType
   at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processClassAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:171)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:125)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2459)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.addAnnotationsDataToClass(MetaDataManager.java:1729)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:173)
   at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager$1.run(MetaDataManager.java:2508)
... 152 more
```

The exception message appears like a typical classloading issue. Apparently the class `javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType` is being loaded twice with different classloaders hence causing the ClassCastException.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?